# Why is my shared folder in openmediavault still referenced?

Tags: openmediavault

I had troubles finding out why the reference tag did not vanish although I removed all referencing (I thought).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that the **backup plugin** also uses a reference and it is now possible to set it to `none` for that reason.

https://github.com/OpenMediaVault-Plugin-Developers/openmediavault-backup/issues/17